# Draw Border around FlatButton when clicked

Tags: flutter, flutter-layout

**Goal:** Drawing a border around the `FlatButton` whenever the user presses that button.

In other words: `onPressed()` is invoked ? -> `DrawBorder()`

---

**Use Case:** The final UI should allow the user to choose multiple Buttons, those chosen buttons should have a border to let the user know that they have been selected.

**Problem:** Can not draw the border programmatically, let alone having multiple buttons (About 9 buttons or so) in the same UI.

[image: Screenshot showing the buttons]

**Button Code:**

```
 FlatButton(
   color: kWhite,
   onPressed: () {},
   child: Image.asset('assets/images/gucci.jpg'),
   shape: RoundedRectangleBorder( //Draw when user clicks on the button 
     side: BorderSide(
     color: kDarkTitleColor, width: 1),
     ),
       padding: EdgeInsets.fromLTRB(10, 10, 10, 10),
      ),
```

Comment: I don't get your problem. Why can't you draw it?
Just move your button to the separate StatefulWidget and handle state changes on tap showing and hiding this border.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can wrap your button in a `StatefulWidget` like this:

```
class BorderedFlatButton extends StatefulWidget {
  @override
  _BorderedFlatButtonState createState() => _BorderedFlatButtonState();
}

class _BorderedFlatButtonState extends State<BorderedFlatButton> {
  bool isSelected = false;

  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return FlatButton(
      color: kWhite,
      onPressed: () {
        print(isSelected);
        setState(() {
          isSelected = !isSelected;
        });
      },
      child: Image.asset('assets/images/gucci.jpg'),
      shape: RoundedRectangleBorder(
        side: BorderSide(
            color: isSelected ? kDarkTitleColor : Colors.transparent, width: 1),
      ),
      padding: EdgeInsets.fromLTRB(10, 10, 10, 10),
    );
  }
}
```

PS: Here I added an state variable `isSelected` that indicated if the button is selected or not.

Comment: make sure to use transparent border color because it's not going to work if you try with width.